# Cos'è "l'ala del vento"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> «Spirito di Luce», diceva il vecchio «Spirito di Saggezza, il
>   cui soffio dà a ogni cosa la sua forma e la riprende; o tu dinnanzi
>   al quale la vita degli esseri è ombra che passa; tu che ascendi le
>   nubi e muovi sull'**ala del vento**; tu che quando spiri, si popolano
>   gli spazi infiniti; che quando inspiri ogni cosa, la quale viene da
>   te, a te ritorna; o moto sempiterno nella sempiterna stabilità; sii
>   benedetto!

Potreste spiegarmi il significato della locuzione "ala del vento"? Ho cercato alla voce "ala" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente a riguardo. Una ricerca su Google però mi ha mostrato che si tratta di un'espressione abbastanza usata.

Comment: È vero, _muoversi sull'ala (o sulle ali) del vento_ è un'espressione molto usata per indicare il librarsi in aria; l'espressione comunica un'immagine di leggerezza e libertà (fa pensare ad esempio ad una foglia o una piuma o un aquilone).
È anche possibile che l'espressione derivi dal concetto fisico della _portanza_ ma questa è solo una mia supposizione ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il riferimento è al salmo 104, versetto 3:

> costruisci sulle acque le tue alte dimore,
>   fai delle nubi il tuo carro,
>   cammini sulle ali del vento,

oppure al salmo 18, versetto 11

> Cavalcava un cherubino e volava,
>   si librava sulle ali del vento.

Si ritrova in [Ossian](https://books.google.it/books?id=FOIIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=on%20the%20wings%20of%20the%20wind%20ossian&source=bl&ots=7AwPRlq5QO&sig=i9sjxEVpP3d-uYfDeuuWlr4bpes&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizjsWy453aAhVJPhQKHdb6A5oQ6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=on%20the%20wings%20of%20the%20wind%20ossian&f=false), per esempio. Molto noto è il lied “Auf Flügeln des Gesanges” di Heinrich Heine (musicato da Mendelssohn), il cui titolo è probabilmente modellato sul biblico “Auf Flügeln des Windes”.

Comment: Questo lied è un [poema di Heinrich Heine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Wings_of_Song_(poem)).